# $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+hy,y)-f(x,y)}{h} = g(x,y)$ in $L^1$ norm implies absolute continuity of $f(\cdot,y)$ with $yf_x'(x,y) = g(x,y)$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, absolute-continuity

Consider the space $L^1(\mathbb{R} \times (0,1))$ with the Lebesgue measure. Let $f,g \in L^1(\mathbb{R} \times (0,1))$ and assume that
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+hy,y)-f(x,y)}{h} = g(x,y)
$$
in $L^1(\mathbb{R} \times (0,1))$ norm.

> I want to prove that $f(\cdot,y)$ is weakly differentiable for almost every $y \in (0,1)$ and $g(x,y) = yf_x'(x,y)$ for almost every $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R} \times (0,1)$.

I argue as follows. We have
\begin{align*}
\int_a^b \frac{f(x+hy,y) - f(x,y)}{h} dx &= \frac 1h \int_{a+hy}^{b+hy} f(x,y) dx - \frac 1h \int_a^b f(x,y) dx\\
&= \frac 1h \int_b^{b+hy} f(x,y) dx - \frac 1h \int_a^{a+ty} f(x,y) dx
\end{align*}
for almost every $y$ (say for $y \in Y \subset (0,1)$ with $Y$ having full measure). Hence
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \int_a^b \frac{f(x+hy,y) - f(x,y)}{h} dx = yf(b,y) - yf(a,y)
$$
for almost every $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ (say for $a,b \in X(y) \subset \mathbb{R}$ with $X(y)$ having full measure in $\mathbb{R}$ for every $y \in Y$).

On the other hand, by assumption,
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \int_{Y'} \int_a^b \frac{f(x+hy,y)-f(x,y)}{h} dx dy = \int_{Y'} \int_a^b g(x,y) dx dy
$$
for any measurable $Y' \subset Y$.

Now it is enough to show that
$$
yf(b,y) - yf(a,y) = \int_a^b g(x,y) dx
$$
but it is not obvious to me. How can I prove that?